What is functorial isomorphism
I am learning triangle categories on the stacks project. In this definition, the author mentions functorial isomorphism $\xi_{X}: F(X[1]) \rightarrow F(X)[1]$.
What is functorial isomorphism? Is this saying that $\xi$ is a natural transformation and $\xi_{X}$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}^{'}$? Or is it just that $\xi_{X}$ is an isomorphism?

Read "functorial isomorphism" as "an isomorphism that is functorial". Functorial means that is really a functor what you have. In your case, that if you have and arrow $F(X[1])\to F(Y[1])$, the $\xi_X$ also associates an arrow $F(X)[1]\to F(Y)[1]$ with the properties of a functor, preserving identities and compositions.

That should say "natural isomorphism," I think (which means that $\xi$ is a natural transformation and $\xi_X$ is always an isomorphism).

For many people "functorial" includes the word "natural" and really just means, "varies well with arrows". However, here it is also an isomorphism of functors so it makes sense to use the word functorial
